# python relative import from same directory doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, relative-import

I have the following directory structure:

```
pkg/
    sub1.py
    sub2.py
```

from withing sub1.py I can successfully import sub2 with: `import pkg.sub2` or with a relative import as `from . import sub2` but I thought the following relative import: `import .sub2` should work as well but it does not. I get a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Because it's not valid syntax ;-) https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports

Comment: The syntax was just not designed to work this way.

Answer (score 0):

`import` doesnot take the `.` this is invalid syntax.

in relative imports always use the `from` keyword! Always!
if you want to use the `import` by its own then this will be an `abs import`. just use :

`import sub2`

generaly speaking, relative imports are risky and try to minimise the usage of this kind of imports.

in your case if you want to import the `sub2.py` module in relative way:
the correct way in python is:

`from . import sub2` as you first typed.

giving one more example for the usage of relative imports. you didnt ask but i found it right to attach this example:

```
pkg/
    sub1.py
    sub2.py
    pkg2/
         foo.py
```

supose i am in foo.py and i want to import from sub1.py the `class clsTemp` then the right way to import this class in relative manner:

```
from ..sub1 import clsTemp
```